# having a problem with this piece of javascript code

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose actions is defined but how do I access this first and second boolean inside someFunction?

is this an object or some kind of destructuring? cause I am getting a some kind of destructuring error.

```
function someFunction(actions, { first = true, second= false }) {      
    if(first == true) {
      console.log("something");
    }
}
```

Error i get -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'first ' of undefined
```

Comment: If you're getting an error then you should always include it in your question.

Comment: @TimLewis this was the code i given and I have to do it that way.

Comment: That's fine, but if the code you were given is not working, you can't really do it that way can you :) Anyway, you've been asked to include the error you're getting, so please update you question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work you have to pass a second parameter when you call the function.
The second argument will be [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment); `delayedActions("foo", "bar")` will work, but `delayedActions("foo", {})` makes more sense.

You can override the default value of recursive:
`delayedActions("foo", { recursive:false })`

The object parameter can include other things not in the function signature object:
`delayedActions("foo", { recursive:true, errorExit:true, fooParam:'bar' })`

Without a second parameter you get an error such as
`VM48976:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'recursive' of undefined`

Comment: Wow, I get exactly that error. thank you so much. Is that just an object? I thought it was default parameter.

Comment: @AlmuntasirAbir well it _is_ a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) but it is an _unnamed_ default parameter. A default parameter would usually have a name... `function delayedActions(actions, config = { recursive = true, errorExit = false })` but that doesn't work with an object param, saying "Invalid shorthand property initializer" — but that may be something I don't understand.